# Asterisk :Don't allow to call if SIP peer is not registered

Tags: android, sip, asterisk, mjsip

I am developing a SIP based application. In general if one registered user of asterisk calls to the user who is not registered, in this scenario call takes some minutes to hangup and user needs to wait sometime to make another call.

So what I want to do is, I don't want to allow a caller to call that peer which is unregistered. So is there any parameter to set in [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) peer settings to do this task.

I am using [sipdroid](http://sipdroid.org/) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Generally, asterisk returns "404 user not found" almost instantly if an user (callee) is not online. But, as per your case, if its taking time, you need to refine the code in siprdoid for response handling.